# uiscrollview within a uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am working on an application where i need to place a uiscrollview within an uiview. The view has a fixed back ground, and in lower half of the view i have to place 30 buttons which scrolls within that area. Lets say the uiview is of 320x480, then the scrollview i have to place will be at (40, 160) to (280, 300). I just need the scroll view to have the 30 buttons inside it. so that view remains fixed, only the buttons can be selected by scrolling vertically. How can i do that?

When i place the scroll view and connect it with file's owner 'view' it eats up all the view space.

Yes, i am a newbie :$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "eats up all the view space"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Add **UIScrollView** to the view:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,160,280,300)];

scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scroll];

//    Now Add your Buttons on this scrollview;
[scroll addSubview:buttonObject];]
```

If you wanted to add 30 buttons, you can use 'for' loops to allocate **UIButton**'s and then add it on scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

The UIViewController sub class (your files owner) will only show the one view you connect to it's view outlet. So you should connect the outer view to files owner, and then add the scroll view to the view by dragging it into the view, and sizing it as you like.

You probably want to create another outlet for the scrollview, so that you also have access to the scrollview from your controller. You could to this by adding the following to you controllers h file and then connecting the scroll view in interface builder.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```